# Why is my SQL OUTPUT statement not working?

Tags: sql, postgresql, sql-insert

When executing the following 2 queries:

```
INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.OrderID 
VALUES ('1');

INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID) 
OUTPUT INSERTED.* 
VALUES ('1');
```

I get the following exception:

> org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: syntax error at or near "OUTPUT"

The Orders table was created using:

```
CREATE TABLE Orders 
(
     OrderID SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, 
     CustomerID int NOT NULL, 

     FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customers(CustomerID)
);
```

What am I doing wrong? Thanks

Comment: Does Postgres have an `OUTPUT`?  I thought it used `RETURNING`.

Comment: Note that `'1'` is a character string, not an integer value. Skip the quoting, and simply do `VALUES (1);` if the ID column data type is integer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Equivalent of `output` in SQL Server is `returning` in PostgreSQL. Please try this.

```
INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID)  
values('1')
returning CustomerID;
```

You can also use * as well

```
INSERT INTO Orders (CustomerID)  
    values('1')
    returning *;
```

Answer (score 1):

The `output` clause is not part of [standard SQL](https://jakewheat.github.io/sql-overview/sql-2016-foundation-grammar.html). It is a [SQL Server extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/output-clause-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15).

The [PostgreSQL equivalent](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/sql-insert.html) is the also non-standard `returning`.

> The optional RETURNING clause causes INSERT to compute and return value(s) based on each row actually inserted (or updated, if an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE clause was used). This is primarily useful for obtaining values that were supplied by defaults, such as a serial sequence number. However, any expression using the table's columns is allowed. The syntax of the RETURNING list is identical to that of the output list of SELECT. Only rows that were successfully inserted or updated will be returned. For example, if a row was locked but not updated because an ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE ... WHERE clause condition was not satisfied, the row will not be returned.

There's no virtual `inserted` table, and it comes at the end of the insert.

```
test=> create table foo ( id bigserial primary key, name text );
CREATE TABLE

test=> INSERT INTO foo (name) VALUES ('test') returning *;
 id | name 
----+------
  1 | test
```